# Using two renders in one outputText in JSF

Tags: jsf

I want a value for a tag where value will be a string based on some code that i will get back in response.
this is my code :

```
<h:outputText styleClass="outputTextWithNonBreakableSpace" 
              id="newBrandValue"
              rendered="#{varnewParty.value == '10001'}"
              value="ABC" 
              converter="com.dwl.datastewardship.web.convert.YesNoConverter"/>

<h:outputText styleClass="outputTextWithNonBreakableSpace" 
              id="newBrandValue2"
              rendered="#{varnewParty.Value == '10002'}"
              value="DEF"   
              converter="com.dwl.datastewardship.web.convert.YesNoConverter"/>
```

Comment: <h:outputText styleClass="outputTextWithNonBreakableSpace"
id="newBrandValue"
rendered="#{varnewParty.value == '10001'}" value="ABC"          converter="com.dwl.datastewardship.web.convert.YesNoConverter"></h:outputText>
<h:outputText styleClass="outputTextWithNonBreakableSpace"
id="newBrandValue2"
rendered="#{varnewParty.Value == '10002'}" value="DEF"          converter="com.dwl.datastewardship.web.convert.YesNoConverter"></h:outputText>

Comment: this is what i am using right now #

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding it into comments.

Comment: you are using XHTML with JSF ?

Comment: it dint allow me with that piece of code to post the wuestion , thats why put it in comment - sorry for that

Comment: yes - taha  , i am not getting the values dsiplayed

Comment: What is the type of varnewParty.value? String or Integer?